# PHP call exe and get return value

Tags: php, exec

In my PHP project, I have an executable (Windows, .exe) which needs to be ran ocassionally by PHP itself. I'm aware of `exec` and `shell_exec` but am not sure whether this is actually what I'm looking for.

The executed application (console application, .NET) returns at least one line in the console, this shall now be grasped by PHP. And I even wonder whether it's possible to get more than one line from the console, so for example if the console's logging what it does?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the manual
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

**$output**
*If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command.*

**$return_var**
If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

**Return Values**
*The last line from the result of the command*. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the passthru() function.

Comment: So if I loop through `$output`, I'll get all of the console's lines?

Comment: Yes, you need to iterate $output array.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use exec, I would use `system`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php

Comment: depends on where you are using it really, sometimes exec is disabled by default.

Comment: oh, and system is more similar to the C one, which is easier to remember for me.
I think is really matter of personal preference, sorry I did not specify that